# how to set space between horizontal <li> to make them recover 100% of the page

Tags: html, css, list, html-lists

I have a list that contain some elements (sometimes there is 3 / sometimes 4 or more...)

What I would like to do is to make them auto adjust to use all the space.

Is there a way in css ? To tell them "hey

I want you to use 100% of the space available" ?

Actualy, it's fine but I want them to use all the space.

this is what I have :
[image]

This is what I would like to have :

[image]

If there is more elements it would be great if it can auto adjust with no changing the css code.

I've tried using `margin:auto` but it did not work.

anykind of help would be much appreciated

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: ...and yes...`flexbox`

Comment: I'm not excpecting that someone do the code for me. I was just lookinf for what to use. I have my own code, and I tried with margin auto but it did not work. If you want me to put the code of my list it would not give any further information. But anyway thank you for the thimbs down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using flexbox. Use the `justify-content` property and set it to `space-between`

Great way to learn flexbox is using these websites:

1. http://flexboxfroggy.com/
2. http://www.flexboxdefense.com/

```css
li{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

ul{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```